# How to convert json data into nested json data format with data grouping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json array as such

```
[{
  id:1,
  topicid : 1,
  Topic:Topic_name,
  categoryid:1,
  category : category_name,
  subcategoryid:1,
  subcategory : subcategory_name,
  pageid: 1,
  pageurl : pageurl_name
}]
```

I want to convert json to below structure  , can you please any one help me make this using jquery or JavaScript .

```
[{
    id :1
    topicid:tiopicid,
    text: "topic_name",
    items: [{
       categoryid:categoryid,
       text: "category_name" ,                           
       items: [{
           subcategoryid:subcategoryid
           text: "subcategory_name"  ,                                    
           items: [{
                 pageid:pageid,
                 text: "pageurl_name"                                        
                  }]
              }]
       }]
}]
```

Comment: How do you know `category` is under `topic`, and `subcategory` under `category`, and `page` under `subcategory`?

Comment: actually i'm creating menu hierarchy , here Topic is the first level then check for category, if it is available then will put it under topic. else under topic will put pagename . if category available then check for subcategory , if it available will put it under category else page name will put under category, in last level will put pageurlname topic and pagename are mandatory fields.

Comment: To rephrase: If you don't already know the structure, how do you know `topic` is the first level, and that you should check for `category`? How would it look like if you had multiple categories? If you already know the structure, then why not simply generate the correct tree in the first place, or write a series of fixed assignments? (BTW, to avoid these misunderstandings, it is always better to make a specific example - say, "Appliance" and "Washing machine" instead of "category_name" and "subcategory_name", and make it complex enough to demonstrate where the complexities of the problem lie.)

Comment: Valid JSON and a few more example elements would be helpful as well. You swap around (what I assume are) different labels (ie, you convert "Topic" to "text".) Is this intentional?

Comment: sorry for invalid details . User name as topic , user role  as category , useraccess as subcategory, page url . Username name in first level then will check for his role , if role is available then check for his access . in user roles we have data like admin, leader ..etc .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are interested in (roughly) normalizing a data set. In this case, grouping is the task. I cleaned up some of the field names to be more consistent and convenient for this particular solution.

Note that this will **not** stop the data from being duplicated in the different subgroups. As in, if the original data duplicates a `pageid` across different topics, both will be written into each topic (there's no database join or references in simple JSON). This may or may not be a problem for you.

I used [Ramda.js](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/index.html), which is a functional Javascript library. This could also be done with lodash, underscore, or even straight JS. jQuery isn't going to help you out here; it's primarily a DOM compatibility library. One last thought before the code: doing this with loops is perfectly possible, but looping mutation is tricky, especially this many levels deep.

### Solution

The task is to take an array of objects, each with the same fields, and progressively group them into container objects. Each object holds the original id, the name of the id, and a list of `items` of sub-objects (the last id lacks this item list) The id buckets are:

```
var ids = ['topic', 'category', 'subcategory', 'page'];
```

So for every id, the data must be:

1. Grouped into arrays of common ids
2. Processed into the container object
3. If any ids remain, all sub-objects are dumped into `items`, being grouped again based on the remaining ids.

Here's the relevant code:

```
(groupIdList, currentDataSet) => {
  var currentId = R.head(groupIdList);
  var remainingIds = R.tail(groupIdList);

  var groupedByCurrentId = R.pipe(
    R.groupBy(R.prop(currentId + 'id')),
    R.map((lst) => {
      // by definition, all elements in the list
      // will have the same id (and barring bad initial data,
      // the same root value) So the guaranteed exisiting first
      // element is used as a template
      var first = R.head(lst);

      // if ids remain, populate the items field
      var obj = remainingIds.length > 0 ? {
        items: groupBy(remainingIds, lst)
      } : {};
      obj[currentId + 'id'] = first[currentId + 'id'];
      obj[currentId] = first[currentId];
      return obj;
    }),
    // groupBy returns an object key/values, and map perserves this.
    // but this function only cares about the values at this point
    R.values
  )(currentDataSet);
  return groupedByCurrentId;
};
```

```js
/* jshint esnext: true */

var rawJson = [{
  "id": 1,
  "topicid": 1,
  "topic": "topic1",
  "categoryid": 1,
  "category": "cat1",
  "subcategoryid": 1,
  "subcategory": "subcat1",
  "pageid": 1,
  "page": "pageurl1"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "topicid": 1,
  "topic": "topic1",
  "categoryid": 1,
  "category": "cat1",
  "subcategoryid": 2,
  "subcategory": "subcat2",
  "pageid": 1,
  "page": "pageurl1"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "topicid": 1,
  "topic": "topic1",
  "categoryid": 1,
  "category": "cat1",
  "subcategoryid": 2,
  "subcategory": "subcat2",
  "pageid": 5,
  "page": "pageurl5"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "topicid": 2,
  "topic": "topic2",
  "categoryid": 4,
  "category": "cat4",
  "subcategoryid": 6,
  "subcategory": "subcat6",
  "pageid": 10,
  "page": "pageurl10"
}];

var groupBy = (groupIdList, currentDataSet) => {
  var currentId = R.head(groupIdList);
  var remainingIds = R.tail(groupIdList);

  var groupedByCurrentId = R.pipe(
    R.groupBy(R.prop(currentId + 'id')),
    R.map((lst) => {
      // by definition, all elements in the list
      // will have the same id (and barring bad initial data,
      // the same root value) So the guaranteed exisiting first
      // element is used as a template
      var first = R.head(lst);

      // if ids remain, populate the items field
      var obj = remainingIds.length > 0 ? {
        items: groupBy(remainingIds, lst)
      } : {};
      obj[currentId + 'id'] = first[currentId + 'id'];
      obj[currentId] = first[currentId];
      return obj;
    }),
    // groupBy returns an object key/values, and map perserves this.
    // but this function only cares about the values at this point
    R.values
  )(currentDataSet);
  return groupedByCurrentId;
};

var ids = ['topic', 'category', 'subcategory', 'page'];

var output = groupBy(ids, rawJson);
console.log(output);

document.getElementById('results').innerText = JSON.stringify(output, null, 2);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.21.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<pre id="results"></pre>
```